# Wikipedia API: how to parse content text into JSON?

Tags: json, wikipedia-api

**EDIT**

Not sure what to do because I realized the question I originally asked was irrelevant to what I really wanted, because I thought the `descriptionurl` and `shortdescriptionurl` from a Wikipedia API query of an image file would return text that described the image, but really they're just descriptions *of the URL*, so I feel dumb about that.

I tried to delete the question but it wouldn't let me, because there's already an answer.

So I'm going to change the question to what I really want to know, but now the answer that already exists will not make any sense, so this is kind of a mess but I don't know what to do about it.

**What I actually wanted to know**

When I do this:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&pageids=18306940&prop=revisions&formatversion=2&rvprop=content
```

I get this:

```
{
"batchcomplete": true,
"query": {
    "pages": [
        {
            "pageid": 18306940,
            "ns": 6,
            "title": "File:Rot-Weiss Essen Fans, May 2008.jpg",
            "revisions": [
                {
                    "contentformat": "text/x-wiki",
                    "contentmodel": "wikitext",
                    "content": "== Summary ==\n{{Information\n|Description=Fans of Rot-Weiss Essen are celebrating a 1-0 away victory against 1. FC Magdeburg in the 2007/08 Regionalliga Nord.\n|Source=I created this work entirely by myself.\n|Date=May 24, 2008\n|Author=[[User:Povldr|Povldr]] ([[User talk:Povldr|talk]])\n|other_versions=\n}}\n== Licensing: ==\n{{self|cc-by-sa-3.0|GFDL}}\n\n{{Copy to Wikimedia Commons|bot=Fbot|priority=true}}"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

What I'd like to do is have the query return only these parts of the content:

- Fans of Rot-Weiss Essen are celebrating a 1-0 away victory against 1. FC Magdeburg in the 2007/08 Regionalliga Nord. (the Description)
- May 24, 2008 (the Date)
- Poldvr (the Author)

I could just get all that out of the content string by chopping up the string in C#, but is there any way to get it spit back to me formatted as nice little JSON in the first place?

I haven't been able to figure this out from [The Wikipedia API page on the `parse` action](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext), nor from the [Wikipedia API Sandbox.](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:ApiSandbox#action=parse&format=json&summary=Some%20%5B%5Blink%5D%5D&pageid=18306940&prop=)

Can it be done?

---

**Here is the old question, which was asking the wrong thing**

title was: *Wikipedia API: how do I use descriptionurl and shortdescriptionurl?*

When I do this, for example:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=allimages&aiprop=url&date&format=json&ailimit=1&aifrom=rot
```

...one of the pieces of JSON info is called "descriptionurl," and another is "shortdescriptionurl."

When I type those urls into a browser, it just takes me to the image's entire page.

How do I use those urls to get just the *text* of the actual description and short description?

Oh, and before you just type the link to the Wikipedia API, I have been trying to find out this information on there and failing. It's full of general information but I can't find this specific thing.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I think you need to do a query, not a parse :)

Answer (score 2):

When I put your URL in a browser, I get some nice JSON as expected:

```
{
    "warnings": {
        "main": {
            "*": "Unrecognized parameter: date."
        }
    },
    "batchcomplete": "",
    "continue": {
        "aicontinue": "Rot-Weiss_Essen_logo.svg",
        "continue": "-||"
    },
    "query": {
        "allimages": [{
            "name": "Rot-Weiss_Essen_Fans,_May_2008.jpg",
            "url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5c/Rot-Weiss_Essen_Fans%2C_May_2008.jpg",
            "descriptionurl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rot-Weiss_Essen_Fans,_May_2008.jpg",
            "descriptionshorturl": "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?curid=18306940",
            "ns": 6,
            "title": "File:Rot-Weiss Essen Fans, May 2008.jpg"
        }]
    }
}
```

To extract an individual entry, you'll need to parse the JSON with your programming language of choice.

Comment: MandyShaw, thanks for answering, I realized that my question was actually completely wrong-headed, and I've reworked the whole question to get at what I am really trying to do.

Comment: I don't know the answer to the new version of the question, sorry!